# Odoo8 - Need a example of ir.actions.server executing multiple actions one after the other

Tags: odoo-8

In a wizzard view I have a button returning pdf report in a 'ir.action.act_url'.  It works fine. Problem is that after the pdf appeared I would like the wizzard window to be closed automatically. To do this I can return close_window dict.

Separately this two 'return' work fine.

I would like to execute two actions, one after another. I found that this is possible using ir.action.server with multi attribute.

Unfortunately I couldn't find even one example.

```
close_window = {'type': 'ir.actions.act_window_close'}

final_report = {
    'type': 'ir.actions.act_url',
    'url': '/web/binary/saveas?model=ir.attachment&field=datas&
    filename_field=name&id=' + str(file.id),
    'target': 'self',
}

return final_report
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `ir_actions` tests that ship with Odoo, they might be able to help you in the right direction.

*base/tests/test_ir_actions.py*

```py
def test_60_multi(self):
    cr, uid = self.cr, self.uid

    # Data: 2 server actions that will be nested
    act1_id = self.ir_actions_server.create(cr, uid, {
        'name': 'Subaction1',
        'sequence': 1,
        'model_id': self.res_partner_model_id,
        'state': 'code',
        'code': 'action = {"type": "ir.actions.act_window"}',
    })
    act2_id = self.ir_actions_server.create(cr, uid, {
        'name': 'Subaction2',
        'sequence': 2,
        'model_id': self.res_partner_model_id,
        'state': 'object_create',
        'use_create': 'copy_current',
    })
    act3_id = self.ir_actions_server.create(cr, uid, {
        'name': 'Subaction3',
        'sequence': 3,
        'model_id': self.res_partner_model_id,
        'state': 'code',
        'code': 'action = {"type": "ir.actions.act_url"}',
    })
    self.ir_actions_server.write(cr, uid, [self.act_id], {
        'state': 'multi',
        'child_ids': [(6, 0, [act1_id, act2_id, act3_id])],
    })

    # Do: run the action
    res = self.ir_actions_server.run(cr, uid, [self.act_id], context=self.context)

    # Test: new partner created
    pids = self.res_partner.search(cr, uid, [('name', 'ilike', 'TestingPartner (copy)')])  # currently res_partner overrides default['name'] whatever its value
    self.assertEqual(len(pids), 1, 'ir_actions_server: TODO')
    # Test: action returned
    self.assertEqual(res.get('type'), 'ir.actions.act_url')

    # Test loops
    with self.assertRaises(except_orm):
        self.ir_actions_server.write(cr, uid, [self.act_id], {
            'child_ids': [(6, 0, [self.act_id])]
        })
```

Have not done it myself, but it looks like you have to specify that it is a `multi` action, and specify the `child_ids` actions to be executed.

Also keep in mind that according to the docs (https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/actions.html):

> multi
>
> Executes multiple actions one after the other. Actions to execute are
>   defined via the `child_ids` m2m. If sub-actions themselves return
>   actions, the last one will be returned to the client as the multi's
>   own next action

Answer (score 0):

According to @dgeorgiev I wrote further code. I managed to create server actions and individually this actions are able to return pdf file or close the window. But I couldn't combine these two return's. See below:

```
# first server action returning pdf 
ir_actions_server = self.env['ir.actions.server']
act1_id = ir_actions_server.create({
    'type': 'ir.actions.server',
    'name': 'divided_package_labels',
    'sequence': 1,
    'model_id': self.id,
    'state': 'code',
    'code': 'action = {"type": "ir.actions.act_url", "url": "/web/binary/saveas?model=ir.attachment&field=datas&filename_field=name&id= %s", "target": "new"}' % str(file.id),
})
# second server action closing window 
act2_id = ir_actions_server.create({
    'type': 'ir.actions.server',
    'name': 'Close_sale.package.wizard',
    'sequence': 2,
    'model_id': self.id,
    'state': 'code',
    'code': 'action = {"type": "ir.actions.act_window_close"}'
})
# server action for combining two previously described
act_id = ir_actions_server.create({
    'type': 'ir.actions.server',
    'name': 'TestAction',
    'condition': 'True',
    'model_id': self.id,
    'state': 'multi',
    # 'child_ids': [(6, 0, [act1_id.id])]  # return pdf
    # 'child_ids': [(6, 0, [act2_id.id])]  # close window
    'child_ids': [(6, 0, [act1_id.id, act2_id.id])]  # close window, no pdf file

})

print act_id, act1_id, act2_id   
print "act_id.child_ids", act_id.child_ids 
# shows that the relations are properly made 

# run
return act_id.run()
```

Probably there is a small mistake, but I couldn't find it.